# gnome : where does my keyboard input go?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, bash, gnome-terminal, vi

I run Ubuntu 16.04, terminals using `gnome-terminal`, and `bash` as shell.

Sometimes, one of my terminal becomes unresponsive : when I press keys on my keyboard while the terminal is focused, nothing happens in it, but the remainder of the system works fine (other programs respond correctly, system wide shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+T</kbd> to open a new terminal work, etc ...)

Most of the time, this happens while I edit a file using `vi`, and maybe it is actually linked to `vi` and not `gnome-terminal` or `bash`, but I also have seen (more rarely though) some of my terminals stuck on the bash command line.

I don't know how to debug this issue.

Questions :

- debugging : how can I view which process has the current focused window ? and maybe view what events it reacts to ?
- Ubuntu / gnome usage : is anyone aware of some keyboard shortcut or some rather standard program, which would somehow redirect keyboard input to something that is not displayed ?

My current blind guess is : there is some shortcut, maybe more easily triggered when typing `vi` commands, that start something which redirects my input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds as if you accidentally hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>. This freezes/stops the terminal. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> to get it going again.

**WARNING:** As you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> all the stuff you typed while the terminal was frozen will be processed. E.g. Start vi and start inserting `Hello` then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> and continue typing `World`. Nothing happens after hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>. Now hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> and the text `World` will be printed.

Btw: This is not a feature of Vi/Vim, but of the terminal or underlying terminal driver.

---

Update:

This seems to be called "XON/XOFF flow control" and it can be disables in the current terminal by executing `stty -ixon`. If you start vi now and start inserting text and then accidentally hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> it will just insert `^S` and continue.

To make this permanent, the command `stty -ixon` must be executed in every terminal (like from your `.bashrc`). 
Note, that there may be side effects!